# Как использовать функцию для определенного блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При наведении на блок меняется текст. Проблема в том что таких блоков несколько и они с одинаковым классом, если я навожу на один блок то другие тоже срабатывают. Мне посоветовали использовать `this`, но поиски в интернете мало что дали.

```js
function f_over () {
  $('.view-car-button-text').css("display","none");
  $('.text-move-on').css("display","block");
}

function f_out () {
  $('.view-car-button-text').css("display","block");
  $('.text-move-on').css("display","none");
}
```

```html
<div class="view-car-button-text" id="view-car-button-text" onmouseover="f_over ();">
  MITSUBISI
</div>
<div class="text-move-on" id="text-move-on" onmouseout="f_out ();">
  <a href="#">ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
</div>
```

Как использовать `this` что бы сработало только на 1 блок?

Comment: блок _text-move-on_ всегда идет сразу после _view-car-button-text_? или могут быть варианты?

Comment: Да всегда. 
Один скрывается а другой становится видимым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что на всех элементах висят функции, которые находят все элементы с заданным классом и естественно ко всем применяют свое действие.
Чтобы использовать this Вам нужно выбрать все элементы с нужным классом и для этой выборки повесить функцию-обработчик, которая будет использовать this.

```
$('.view-car-button-text').on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).css("display","none");
        $(this).next($('.text-move-on')).css("display","block");
      });

  $('.text-move-on').on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).css("display","none");
    $(this).prev($('.view-car-button-text')).css("display","block");
  });
```